# Unable to retrieve data from axios GET request

Tags: javascript, axios

I've been trying to send a GET request to an api to fetch data using Axios but always get a response object with status, headers, config, agents etc and response.data is always empty.

For example, the following code returns me an Axios response object with the hasBody set to true and data being empty.

```
axios.get(`https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/leagues-classic/12000/standings/`).then(response => {console.log(response); 
console.log(response.data);});
```

However, when I switched over to using Request library which has been deprecated, I am able to get the response body. For example, the following code works:

```
request(`https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/leagues-classic/12000/standings/`, { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
        if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        console.log(body);
        });
```

Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and how can I get the response body using axios? I'm a beginner and have spent hours trying to figure out so I would really appreciate any form of help.

Comment: why type of data does the server return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an `axios` library issue. From what I can tell, the server does't like the user-agents starting with "axios/". Specifying some user agent gives you the expected result:

```
const axios = require("axios");
axios.get(`https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/leagues-classic/12000/standings`, {
    headers: {
        'user-agent': 'not axios', 
    }
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

As for why the `requests` library works but `axios` does not: axios is setting the `user-agent` header to something like `axios/0.21.1` or whatever version you have. `requests` on the other side, leaves the `user-agent` header unset. It's the server right to handle the request as he pleases.

Answer (score -1):

I have verified the response from this URL https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/leagues-classic/12000/standings/ - there is no data property in the response

Try like below to read the values:
[image]

Comment: Hi Krishna, the issue is that the response itself is not in json format for me to destructure. I keep getting an axios response object.

Answer (score -1):

It seem like your URL at https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/leagues-classic/12000/standings/ had invalid response body.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help man. I am able to get the data in the url using Request library but not with Axios. So does it have really anything to do with the url?